# What is an efficient way to get an array of property values from a core data entity?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

Consider the following:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest Alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityWithName:@"Person" inContext:_MOC];
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Name"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [_MOC executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

This returns an array of `Person` objects. What I want is an array of `Person.name` values from those objects. Currently I walk the results array, extract the names and build a new array. Is there a cleaner, faster way to do this? I've thought about changing `request.resultType` to `NSDictionaryResultType` but that doesn't buy much as I still need to transform the array of dictionary into the array I need.

I already have the solution above implemented, so really looking for a better way. If the correct answer is "there is no better way" that's fine, just making sure I'm not missing something. Thanks!

EDIT: while thinking about this, I'm questioning my need for an array of values vs. just using the array of managed objects. In any case, would still appreciate a great answer if there's one out there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ask for `NSDictionaryResultType`, and then with the resulting array of dictionaries, just ask for `[array valueForKey:@"name"]`. When an `NSArray` receives `-valueForKey:` it returns a new `NSArray` created from the results of calling `-valueForKey:` on all its elements.

Comment: cool, didn't realize `valueForKey` walked the array for you. wouldn't that would work on the array of managed objects as well?

Comment: @XJones: I imagine so, yes, but if you just want to extract a property, then it's almost certainly simpler/more efficient to grab dictionaries instead of full managed objects.

Comment: perhaps, though not sure why. I'm already restricting my request to just the property I care about. in terms of performance (speed & memory footprint) don't know if NSDictionary vs NSManagedObject will make any significant difference here. In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to have the fetch request itself return the array of values but I don't think that's possible. Using `valueForKey:` with an array is a nice optimization, if nothing else I let the framework walk the array for me. +1 and accept (unless an answer appears that directly returns the array of values from the fetch request). thanks again.